# rubymine で下に出てくる Messages などの画面をショートカットで閉じるには？

Tags: rubymine

rubymine で下に出てくる Messages などの画面をショートカットで閉じるには、
なんのキーを押したらよいのでしょう？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2017.1/messages-tool-window.html

`Cmd + 0`

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このように数字が書いてあるものは `Cmd + 数字` で閉じたり開いたりできます。

Answer (score 0):

数字がついていないのも<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd>で閉じれます。（開けないですが）